# Proving subadditivity of max norm for matrices

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

I'm having struggle with proving that function given by $max(|a_{ij}|)$ for a 3-by-3 matrix A is norm.

Showing positivity and homogeneity is trivial, but I'm struggling with triangle inequality property.

According to the definition 
$||A+B|| = max(|a_{ij}+b_{ij}|)$, but $||A||$ might just as well be $max(|a_{kl}|)$, with $k$ and $l$ different from $i$ and $j$. The same goes with $||B||$. How to show that regardless of that the property still holds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the common notation for the matrix maximum norm
$$ 
\Vert A \Vert_\infty = \max_{i, j} |a_{ij}|
$$
we have that for all possible indices $i, j$
$$
|a_{ij} + b_{ij}| \le |a_{ij}| + | b_{ij}| \le \Vert A \Vert_\infty  + \Vert B \Vert_\infty  \, .
$$
The last expression does not depend on $i,j$, therefore
$$
\Vert A+B \Vert_\infty \le \Vert A \Vert_\infty  + \Vert B \Vert_\infty \, .
$$

Comment: What exactly does $\infty$ denote here?

Comment: @randomguy: That is a common notation for the max norm.

Comment: @randomguy The max norm is the $p\to\infty$ limit of the $L^p$ norm, which is denoted with a $p$ subscript.